# Switch users batch file on a PC with ForceAutoLogon

Tags: windows, batch

I would like to run a batch file to get to the login page. Is there a way to bypass the `ForceAutoLogon` setting in a batch file, like you can with `shift` and GUI menus?

---

I have a PC with a default user account that is logged in on start-up, and the lock screen is disabled.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon]
"AutoRestartShell"=dword:00000001
"DefaultDomainName"="SomeDomain"
"DefaultUserName"="GenericAccount"
"DefaultPassword"="SomePassword"
"AutoAdminLogon"="1"
"ForceAutoLogon"="1"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]
"DisableLockWorkstation"="1"
"DisableChangePassword"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]
"DisableLockWorkstation"="1"
"DisableChangePassword"=dword:00000001
```

---

My end user will need to log into a different account from time to time. Due to the `ForceAutoLogon` setting, they won't be able to get to the login screen. In my research to find a solution I learned that you can hold `shift` when using menus to bypass the autologin:

- switch users from the start menu
- lock from the start menu
- switch users from CTRL + ALT + DELETE menu

But this is a solution the end-user finds cumbersome.

I cannot permanently disable `ForceAutoLogon` and as the user is not an admin so the method should not require admin access to switch users on every run.

Comment: Do you want to switch to the other user or log out the first user and then login to the second user? In case you want to log out, `shutdown /l` should be what you want. It will log out the current user and the force auto logon section is ignored and a logon screen is presented.

Comment: Are you able to run remote commands against the machine? Is the auto logged on user a local administrator on the machine or not?

Comment: @LPChip I just tried your suggestion, the account set up with the `ForceAutoLogon` just logged back in.

Comment: @PillsburyITDoughboy The auto logged in account is not an admin.

Comment: Can you run remote commands against the machine with an admin account? I have a solution if that's possible which I've used so let me know.

Comment: @PillsburyITDoughboy if it would need admin access to run on every execution then no, but if it would only be needed for set up then yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Turn off `ForceAutoLogon` so autologon account can logoff

Since the autologin account is not a local admin, you are likely going to have to toggle off the `ForceAutoLogon` registry value and then logoff the account remotely.

Once that option is disabled and the account is logged off, you will then be able to log in as usual via Remote Desktop Connection or at the console with the other account.

Run this batch from a machine with an account that has admin access to the remote machine you are working with to disable `ForceAutoLogon`.

#### Remote Batch (disable `ForceAutoLogon`)

```
SET /P "RemotePC=Enter Remote PC Name: "
REG ADD "\\%RemotePC%\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v "ForceAutoLogon" /t "REG_SZ" /d "0" /f
for /L %%a in (1,1,99) do Logoff %%a /server:%RemotePC%
```

Now do whatever work needs to be done on the machine with the account that does not automatically login since you can log in with it now.

Once that work is complete, you can run the below batch file to re-enable  `ForceAutoLogon` again. After that reboot and auto login will start working again for the kiosk account.

#### Remote Batch (enable `ForceAutoLogon`)

```
SET /P "RemotePC=Enter Remote PC Name: "
REG ADD "\\%RemotePC%\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v "ForceAutoLogon" /t "REG_SZ" /d "1" /f
```

> **Note:** If able to setup Computer Configuration Group Policy Preferences to set the specific registry values for the kiosk machine
> auto login, you would only need to reboot for the auto login to start
> working again without running the script to re-enable.

#### Supporting Resources

- [reg add](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg-add)
- [Logoff](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/logoff)
- [FOR /L](https://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html)

  > ```
  > FOR /L %variable IN (start,step,end) DO command [command-parameters]
  >
  >     The set is a sequence of numbers from start to end, by step amount.
  >     So (1,1,5) would generate the sequence 1 2 3 4 5 and (5,-1,1) would
  >     generate the sequence (5 4 3 2 1)
  > ```

Comment: This example assumes you are running as a batch script against the remote match while logged onto the machine which has administrator permission to the remote machine (e.g. domain admin). You'd obviously need to set the value back to enabled for the autologin to work again after you are done with the work of the account you did which is not the auto login ID you use.

Comment: Sorry I feel I miss lead you, one thing I can't do is disable `ForceAutoLogon` permanently as it is required if the kiosk account is used

Comment: @Nifim You would then just re-enable the auto-login detail with a script that changes that back to a `1` value which I can write up another script to do that which you can run remotely or while logged on the machine not with the auto login account that is a local admin. I assume you need to toggle it off, do something, and then turn it back on. You could even use Group Policy Preferences if applicable to set that back after a reboot if you made this remote change too. I do it both ways in an environment I support for some machines.

Comment: @Nifim I just edited my answer for you with a way to turn on and off. Unless you setup a local or domain group policy or some sort of startup script to change the applicable registry values you change with the batch, you will have to turn it off and on manually but remotely when you are ready. If you are logged onto the machine as an admin for the work you do after disabling the auto login, you can run the reg add command locally on the machine and reboot when done too. You can automate a log here because I do it myself for some systems.

Comment: @Nifim If you can make the reg add and logoff commands run without the `\\<remotemachinename>` remote logic and hold down shift and right click to select run as different user on the machine of the auto logged in account locally too. You'd still need to turn it back on once complete though unless those configs were automated with GPP or a start up script. Okay, done pining you until I hear back to give you time.

Comment: I have added more details to my question, the batch file is for an end user to run so they can login.

Comment: @Nifim You might be able to grant that non-admin account(s) permission to the registry keys to make those changes as needed with the batch as a workaround or have them use some sort of saved proxy admin account as wrote about here https://serverfault.com/questions/734320/allow-standard-user-to-run-program-as-local-admin-without-elevation-prompt/734360#734360 to execute the batch script rather than that app. Maybe there is another way but starting to get too complex really. On the business side in my case, they get one or the other or separate machines to login to that are not kiosk/autologon.

Comment: @Nifim If it starts getting complex for something they'd like, it might make sense to start talking about having kiosk machines dedicated for that purpose and have non-kiosk machines available for other purposes. I don't know your environment or constraints and requirements, but these are usually admin level things and when that is required, there are security considerations so they may be better off using separate machines for non-kiosk machines. Just my 2 cents but there you have it. Good luck  and I hope you find a suitable and reasonable solution regardless.

Comment: That is an interesting idea, I will look into giving that a try. separate machines would be the case here as well; however, when I requested a new computer I was told I would not get a date of a possible delivery until August.